# How do I create a function that creates a new dataframe column based on search words that exist in an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that is flexible enough to output a `string` based on search words that are in an existing DataFrame column. I am getting an output but it seems every output after the first is chained with the previous outputs (previous outputs repeat with the new output). How can I correct this? I plan to expand the function to include more `for loops`. Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
# declarations
search_words = ['one', 'two', 'three']
l1 = []

#Function
def concat(text):
    for i in search_words[0:1]:
        if i in text:
            a = 'four'
            l1.append(a)
    for i in search_words[1:3]:
        if i in text:
            b = 'five'
            l1.append(b)
    listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, l1))
    return listToStr

# Test Dataframe
dftest = pd.DataFrame(data =['one filler two','two','filler','three one'], 
                      columns = ['col1'])

# Test output
dftest['col2'] = dftest['col1'].apply(lambda x: concat(x))
dftest
```

wrong output given:

```
    col1               col2
0   one filler two     four five
1   two                four five five
2   filler             four five five
3   three one          four five five four five
```

Desired output:

```
    col1               col2
0   one filler two     four five
1   two                five
2   filler             
3   three one          five four
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a new `l1` each time you call `concat`:

```
def concat(text):
    l1 = []
    for i in search_words[0:1]:
        if i in text:
            l1.append('four')
    for i in search_words[1:3]:
        if i in text:
            l1.append('five')
    listToStr = ' '.join(l1)
    return listToStr
```

Also when you apply `concat`, you don't need lambda:

```
dftest['col2'] = dftest['col1'].apply(concat)
```

Output:

```
             col1       col2
0  one filler two  four five
1             two       five
2          filler           
3       three one  four five
```

Answer (score 0):

One simpler way might be:

```py
dict_assignment = {
    "one": "four",
    "two": "five",
    "three": "five",
}

dftest["col2"] = dftest.col1.apply(
    lambda p: ' '.join(dict_assignment[w] for w in p.split() if w in search_words)
)

print(dftest)

#              col1       col2
# 0  one filler two  four five
# 1             two       five
# 2          filler           
# 3       three one  five four
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` to call a function that contains a loop will be extremely inefficient.

Use vectorial code instead and a dictionary that maps the word, then join to the original dataframe.

```
d = {'one':'four', 'two':'five', 'three':'five'}

df2 = dftest.join(
 dftest['col1']
 .str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(d)})")[0]
 .map(d)
 .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
 .rename('col2')
 )
```

*NB. I used a simple regex here, however if you have special characters in your query words, you might need to escape them using `re.escape`. Please update the example of this is the case.*

Output:

```
             col1       col2
0  one filler two  four five
1             two       five
2          filler        NaN
3       three one  five four
```